# Deconstruct unification of singleton types to its constituents

Tags: scala, types, shapeless, type-level-computation

I'm playing with singleton types, and based on one of Miles Sabin's code snippets I have this:

```
scala> trait Param[K] { self =>
     |   type V
     | }
defined trait Param

scala> def param[V0](key: String): Param[key.type] { type V = V0 } = new    Param[key.type] { type V = V0 }
param: [V0](key: String)Param[key.type]{type V = V0}


scala>   val r = param[Int]("q")
r: Param[String("q")]{type V = Int} = $anon$1@770c789a

scala>   val s = param[String]("s")
s: Param[String("s")]{type V = String} = $anon$1@9e77ebd
```

So far so good, but now say I have an expression:

```
scala>   val ff = if (true) {
    |     r
    |   } else {
    |     s
    |   }
ff: Param[_ >: String("q") with String("s") <: String]{type V >: Int with String} = $anon$1@770c789a
```

Looking at the type of the expression, it seems the that K and V where unified to  String("q") with String("s") and Int with String respectively

That kind of makes sense, but now my question is if it's possible to "deunify" or coerce this type to it's constituents i.e. the types of r and s above.

Something like the following, converting to tuple:

```
Param[K0 with K1] { type V: V0 with V1 } -> (Param[K0] { type V: V0}, Param[K1] { type V: V1})
```

I'm looking for something purely at the type level. Any chance there's a mechanism to deconstruct the unified type ?